# Image does not display well on iphone even with max-width:100%

Tags: javascript, css

i am working on my website: http://www.antologiaoliveoil.com/ES/index.html

All looking good, however, when I preview this on Iphone, the image called Lataorganica.jpg does not display well on the first time it shows up on vertically, and the slider does not work. Once I rotate the iPhone horizontally, and then back vertically it works fine.

any idea anyone?

Many thanks

Comment: You could make your question easier for us to answer by providing more details - such as iPhone / browser version

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem you have is that your text is in your image.  On an iPhone or other mobile device where the width is very small, all the text is squish into the image because the image is squish into the mobile width.

One way to fix that is to create separate mobile slider image where there is less text and it is easier to read on a mobile.  You can use CSS Media Queries to trigger the mobile slider to show if the width is small.

As for your question about the slider, are you using Owl Carousel (http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/)?  If you are, include the code you are using so we know how to troubleshoot.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, thanks so much for your reply. I am not sure what you mean that my text in my image. Which part of the code exactly? The html? css? JS?

Comment: That's the problem.  The image and the text are together -> http://www.antologiaoliveoil.com/ES/images/slider/antologia/antologiaPortada.jpg.    

On Mobile, the screen is so small that the text is squished bc it is part of the image.  This is not good practice.  You can use CSS to overlay the text above the image.

Comment: thanks for this, but I never refered to those images. I was talking about these ones. <img src="images/lataVirgen.jpg" alt="image description">

Answer (score 0):

He is using owl carousel. I see you are also using bootstrap.  Is there a reason you are not using the bootstrap carousel? See here for [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp)

You have the required files to use the linked solution.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, why using bootstrap instead of owl? My wish is basically that images always fits screen no matter what.